# Можно ли в QTableWidget вставить dataframe?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pandas

Начал изучать [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5) и ни как не могу найти как сделать так чтобы в таблицу (`QTableWidget`) вставить pandas таблицу, в которой есть названия строк и столбцов.

Может есть какие книги где пишут как реализовать что то подобное?

[image: пример dataframe]

Comment: Никак. Qt это с++ библиотека, а pandas -- python библиотека, поэтому только руками добавлять из dataframe в tableWidget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3c908e99e5f96738d0726a072718bb2ffba72cff/pandas__examples/show%20dataframe%20in%20QTableWidget.py) заполнения `QTableWidget` из dataframe `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


# Подготовка данных
records = [
    (1, 'Vasya', 16),
    (2, 'Vasya2', 18),
    (3, 'Vasya3', 34),
    (4, 'Vasya4', 10),
    (5, 'Vasya5', 19),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=records, columns=['ID', 'NAME', 'AGE'])
headers = df.columns.values.tolist()

# Отображение данных на виджете
app = QApplication([])

table = QTableWidget()
table.setColumnCount(len(headers))
table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # Добавление строки
    table.setRowCount(table.rowCount() + 1)

    for j in range(table.columnCount()):
        table.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[j])))

table.show()

app.exec()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! а можно ещё сделать так чтобы вместо цифр в названии строк были слова?

Comment: В QTableWidget? Используя setVerticalHeaderLabels можно указать название в ячейках в первой колонке, либо спрятать первую колонку, которая по умолчанию видна: table.verticalHeader().hide()

Comment: В Кутэ есть же модели https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html нужно просто описать пару методов на питоне и будет двухсторонняя связь

Comment: @eri, ну да, можно, и даже не от базовой модели, а от табличной https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstracttablemodel.html. Но это потребует больше кода. Сделайте это сами и в добавьте в ответ, я поставлю плюс :)